# Dialogue help please!

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

Sometimes when I'm in dialogue there is a glitch when you don't choose an option the bar gets empty and people make suggestions. However this time I was talking to Ellegard about the Witherstorm and stuff and I had no option and the screen stayed like that for a very long time like in a loop. Here's and example of what I'm talking about [not my video]:

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be really a solution to this from what I know, except restarting the chapter.
That's from what I know, at least.